# Support modelling cycle through differentiated means

Tags: secondary-education, applied-mathematics, applications

I plan to work with my students on solving real-world problems through modelling them. Now it is my idea to follow the modelling cycle below.

[image]

The idea is to find with the help of two values that have been investigated by an institute for market research the point of maximum profit located on the inverse demand function. This function takes a certain quantity of a good and maps to it the price per unit the vendor can take.

So far for the background. Do you see a way to differentiate working on this topic except of beeing open in which ways of modelling are accepted as adequate?

Comment: I assume that by "differentiate" you mean "tailor instruction to meet individual needs."  Is this for high school students or for undergraduates?

Comment: "tailor instruction to meet individual needs" is exactly what I mean. The students are high school students. My idea was to accompany the work with help cards but I don't think that this is the right way to accompany their work since this leads thier work what I want to avoid.